# PostgreSQL: Delete duplicate rows based on matching md5 hashes

Tags: postgresql, md5, postgresql-14, drop-duplicates

I have a table which is populated by data scraped from the web. After adding the new data to the table I want to delete duplicates if no changes have been made to specific columns.

I have tried the following query along with various ways of referencing the md5 hash, and casting column1 as text:

```sql
DELETE FROM
    my_table a
        USING my_table b
WHERE
    a.pk < b.pk
    AND a.md5(column1) = b.md5(column1);
```

and receive the following error:

> ```
> ERROR: column reference "column1" is ambiguous 
> LINE 6: AND a.md5(column1) = b.md5(column1); 
>                   ^ 
> SQL state: 42702 Character: 99
> ```

Comment: Try: AND md5(a.column1) = md5(b.column1);

Comment: @Soren thank you very much that's resolved to problem, thanks for responding so quickly

Comment: Try `a.column1=b.column1` - it'll be faster and more reliable if you let Postgres figure out the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't deduplicate based on `md5()`, just use `=`

Let Postgres [figure out](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-optimizer.html) if it benefits from hashing at all, and if so, what the optimal hashing function should be. It's easier for you to declare, easier for Postgres to optimise and execute. SQL is meant to be declarative - state *what* you want, not *how exactly* it's supposed to be done.

That way you also avoid potentially incorrect results - md5 sticks around just for simplicity but it has long been considered unreliable. It's rare but not impossible for your values to be completely different but share the same md5, so you may get undeserved deletes.

If Postgres sees the values are too long to be compared with a plain `=` effectively, it'll change the value equality into value hash equality behind the scenes, using a hashing function of its own choice:

```
explain analyze verbose
DELETE FROM my_table a
USING my_table b
WHERE a.pk < b.pk
AND a.column1 = b.column1
returning *;
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Delete on public.my_table a (cost=3758.00..10978.49 rows=7480 width=650) (actual time=26.669..68.048 **rows=1858** loops=1) |
| ... |
| -> **Hash Join** (cost=3758.00..10978.49 rows=7480 width=650) (actual time=26.642..64.441 rows=1985 loops=1) |
| ... |
| **Hash Cond**: (a.column1 = b.column1) |
| ... |
| -> **Hash** (cost=1867.00..1867.00 rows=20000 width=644) (actual time=26.444..26.445 rows=20000 loops=1) |
| ... |
| Execution Time: **68.541 ms** |

Notice how the version with `md5` affects the exact same amount of rows, just 4 times slower: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/NkKabbb6)

```
explain analyze verbose
DELETE FROM my_table a
USING my_table b
WHERE a.pk < b.pk
AND md5(a.column1) = md5(b.column1)
returning *;
```

|  |
| --- |
| Delete on public.my_table a (cost=18078.54..63328.54 rows=666667 width=650) (actual time=215.633..249.269 **rows=1858** loops=1) |
| Output: a.pk, a.column1, b.pk, b.column1 |
| -> **Merge Join** (cost=18078.54..63328.54 rows=666667 width=650) (actual time=215.603..246.022 rows=1985 loops=1) |
| ... |
| Execution Time: **252.893 ms** |

As a bonus, if future versions of Postgres get improved in terms of the hash-based operations, you'll get that for free with `=`, without having to revisit and update any code.

Comment: Excellent thank for the answer and the demo. I have a database which is 75 columns wide and I want keep the new record if any of 8 key records have changed. Will this scale in a linear fashion

Comment: I would need an example of the comparison/deduplication you describe (I did not quite get the *any of 8 key records* idea in this context) but yes, you can expect this to scale linearly.